# Updating mySQL field where there are multiple matches

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a field in a MySQL table of around 4,000 records where the email
addresses matches about 90 email addresses.

I have looked through past answers and tried to get it right but seem to be getting more errors.

I am using phpMyAdmin and this is what I first started off with:

```
UPDATE `user_table`.`eb_users` SET `pause` = 'X' WHERE `eb_users`.`email` LIKE   ('test1@test1.com', 'another@another.com', 'moreemail@email.com');
```

The above throws the "Operand should contain 1 column(s) error" - I then tried different
variants of the above and got similar errors.

It's probably basic but am just not getting it... any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know all of the email addresses you need to match then you can look for matches against a collection using `IN` rather than `LIKE`

```
UPDATE `user_table`.`eb_users` SET `pause` = 'X' WHERE `eb_users`.`email` IN   ('test1@test1.com', 'another@another.com', 'moreemail@email.com');
```

Comment: Thanks Matt - brilliant that's fixed it - guess I wasn't that far out but it's taken too long.. still learning :-)